# Moving hard disk blocks after deleting file

Tags: windows, hard-drive, defragment

When deleting a file in windows (and maybe in other operating systems too), it leaves a free zone in the hard disk.

**Example:**

Here is a representation of hard disk blocks (blue square represents a block in use and white square represents a free block):

[image: Click to see image]

After deleting a large file it would look like that:

[image: Click to see image]

The deleted file left a "hole" in the hard disk.

I want to fix all the "holes".
I mean, that I want to move all the blocks after each "hole" backwards, so that there will not be any holes.

The reason I want to do this is because I don't want that new files will be fragmented because of the "holes".

**So, my question is:** Is there a way or a tool that I can use to move hard disk blocks so that there will not be any free space in the middle of the hard disk after deleting files?

Comment: Defragmenter of your choice.  Use your choice of tool.  I suggest using the built-in tool.  Please use better tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing
[Defragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defragmentation),
which exists since the time that hard disks were invented.

For a review of defragmentation products, see
[Best Free Disk De-fragmenter](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-de-fragmenter.htm).

Comment: I know that defragmentation combines parts of files into one consecutive file on disk.
But does it also do what I have described in the answer?
I mean to the built-in deframentation software of windows 7.

Comment: Yes it does. If you want ultimate control you can write a program that uses the Windows API (start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363911(v=vs.85).aspx)).